# Linked Accounts Getting Confused?

Tags: bug, user-accounts

I have two different email addresses linked to my Stack Exchange ID. I *thought* I had different passwords for them, and when I look at my profile, it *appears* to treat them as different, but linked.

However, when I went to recover my password for my *work* email, the link asked me to change the password for my *home* email.

Now, I can't recover my password for my *work* email; it's too many recovery requests too quickly.

Is this correct behavior? I want to have separate passwords for both emails, but I want them linked since I'm the same person either way and want to access the same stacks and accumulate rep et cetera.

NB: When I changed the password using the link sent to me *at my work address*, it did in fact change the password for my *home* address. I cannot change the password for my work address because it is not the same as the password for my home address, I have forgotten what it is, and the system will not let me recover it.

Comment: I want separate passwords and separate emails, but the same account, because I do not want to have anything _personal_ being used from my work computer, and if I am at home, I do not have access to the work email if I need to recover a password or receive a SE notification.

Comment: When you went to recover the password for your 'work' email, the link asked you to change it for 'home', and when you changed the password, it did just that? Can you maybe tell us the exact, chronological steps of what happened?

Comment: 1. My workstation at work rebooted overnight. 2. I brought everything back up, but every SE site presented me with the login button. 3. I tried to login, but couldn't remember the work address password. 4. I clicked on the recover password link. 5. I received the email at my work address. 6. I cutpasted the link into my SE browser (Chrome; the default browser here is Edge). (_more..._)

Comment: (_...more_) 7. The system asked me for a new password for the HOME address, and I figured it was just an error, and it would change the correct address's password. It didn't, it changed my home address's password. (I had recovered the home address last night from home). 8. I tried logging in with the work address and the new password. No go. I logged in with the home address and the new password. It worked. I logged out, and tried to log in with the work address, and failed; this time, it said too many recovery requests and wouldn't let me try to recover.

Comment: Right now, I'm logged in with my home address and password I just set for it, and somewhat upset because I really don't want to be - but I want to be logged in to SE so that I can read/answer questions, get rep, et cetera.

Comment: I should note that when I recovered the password last night from home for the home address, it accepted a password that was all lowercase plus digits. Today, it required a much more complex password.

Comment: (It is several hours later, and when I try to recover the password for the work address, I am still being told "too many recovery requests, please try again later". When can I try again?)

Comment: Sounds like your accounts got merged, not linked. Your only option is to contact staff by sending contact form, but even for them it's nearly impossible to undo a merge. Next time use different accounts and never interact between them.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard - Your "merged" vs my "linked" may be a terminology difference rather than a real "structural" distinction; the idea really is that I want to have one identity and one "rep bank" for any given Stack, but depending on where I am/what device I'm using, I want to be able to use distinct email addresses and passwords.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard - the problem is that in some ways it seems to maintain two separate email accounts/passwords - but something got screwed and I can't access it with one of the email addresses and can't "fix" the password for that address.